# Chart goes out of container

Tags: javascript, css

If the user hover over a section in the main-section a popup is opened in which important data is displayed in a chart. This chart moves with the position of the mouse. Now it is possible that the chart goes out of the main-section and is overlayed by the side-section.

[image]

My goal is to set a min x position which the popup has to have. I already tried to adapt the JavaScript based calculation and to set css-styles but it hasn't worked and I don't know how I could solve it.

How can I tell the popup that it can only moves till the end of it's main-container?

**Edit: I use Angular and added the html and scss code.**

```js
public moveValueChart(event) {
  let elementRect = (event.target as HTMLElement).getBoundingClientRect();
  let x = event.clientX - event.target.clientWidth / 2 - elementRect.width;
  this.valueChartPopup.nativeElement.style.transform = `translateX(${x}px)`;
}
```

```css
 .padding-m {
      padding: 8px;
    }

    .full-size {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .flex {
      display: flex;
     }
     
     .card {
      border: 1px solid #ecf5f5;
      box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
      border-radius: 8px;
      background: white;
    }
```

```html
<div
      class="card flex full-size padding-m"
    >
      <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
        <ng-container matColumnDef="code" sticky>
          <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell
            *matCellDef="let row"
            (mouseover)="openValueChart(row.code, $event)"
            (mousemove)="moveValueChart($event)"
            (mouseout)="closeValueChart()"
            >{{ row.code }}</mat-cell
          >
        </ng-container>
        <mat-header-row
          *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"
        ></mat-header-row>
        <mat-row
          *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"
        ></mat-row>
      </mat-table>

      <section #chart class="value-chart-popup">
        <div class="value-chart" *ngIf="displayChart">
          <value-chart
            [values]="values"
            [valueLabel]="selectedValueLabel"
          ></value-chart>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
```

Comment: It would be useful to have more context, perhaps a simplified example with all the necessary code? The problem here is that we cannot see what elements you have or what styles you have on those elements.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Sure. I added the html and css code.